# Writing a parser

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

Writing SQL like parser in .NET

At this point on the first basic parse

select col1, col2, col4 from documents where col1 any ('a','b','c') and col2 all ('b','c')

I can identify what I call all the token type

select is select
col1 is column
col2 is column
from is from
where is where
col1 is column
any is condition
('a','b','c') is multi value

I am having trouble with the next level of rules

After select it must be a column that is easy

After a column before the from valid syntax is
   , column
or from

It looks like I never need to go forward or back more than two to determine if token type is valid

What is the correct (or good) methodology / approach

Maybe I don't need to roll by hand but column names and table names is dynamic so I kind of felt like code was the way to go.  Also for silly reasons I don't want to use a library outside of .NET.

Comment: Is there any good reason why you're not using a parser generator?

Comment: @whatsisname Maybe because I don't know what that is.  Could you point me to one to look at.   I am mathematician that got into computing via numerical methods.  So I am at a real loss here compared to a computer science degree.   I have never written a parser before and this is probably the last I will ever need to.

Comment: [Parser Generators for C#](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+parser+generator).  My favorite is [Irony](https://irony.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 4):

You can't go wrong if you learn how to write a [*recursive descent parser*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

They are fast, easy to write, and you don't need any special tools.

That's what the pros do.
For example the [*GCC Parser*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6319216/23771) is hand-written recursive descent.

ADDED, because you're confused:
Here is some pseudo-code to try to give you the general idea. I purposely left out details and left in problems for you to figure out and/or modify as you see fit:

```
parsValues(){
    if (parsLiteral()){
    } else if (parsChar('('){
        do {
            if (!parsLiteral()) ERROR...
        } while (parsChar(','));
        if (!parsChar(')')) ERROR...
    } else {
        ERROR...
    }
}

parsAnyAll(){
    if (parsWord("any") || parsWord("all")){
        parsValues()
    } else {
        ERROR...
    }
}

parsAnd(){
    parsAnyAll()
    while(parsWord("and")){
        parsAnyAll()
    }
}

parsOr(){
    parsAnd()
    while(parsWord("or")){
        parsAnd()
    }
}

parsSelect() {
    do {
        if (!parsColName()) ERROR("colname expected");
    } while (parsChar(','));
    if (!parsWord("from")) ERROR ...
    if (!parsTableName()) ERROR ...
    if (parsWord("where")){
        parsOr()
    }
}
```

Comment: Recursive decent is what I kind of stumbled on.  I will try and fight through it.

Comment: @Paparazzi: The main thing is to see that recursive parse tree rules can simply be represented by recursive functions. Also, it requires the mental idea of *lookahead*. That means you don't read a symbol and then decide what it is. Rather, it's *already* been read. You decide what it is and then you *accept* it (which reads the next one). This is a key concept. Once those ideas are in your head, you will be glad you got them.

Comment: @Paparazzi: There are constructions that are tricky for recursive-descent. Like in C-ish you can write `A + ((((int))))(B+C)`. It's hard to know when you see `(` whether it leads into a cast or a parenthesized sub-expression. For those, it might be cleaner to use a shift-reduce parser, but I've written many parsers and never needed that, and I doubt if you will either.

Comment: Exactly!   Parenthesized sub-expression is my my biggest challenge.  I know what  value expression looks like "('a','b','c')" so my plan is to token them.  So now a parenthesis has to stand up to a logic expression.   Another real problem is 'cant'''.  Need to parse it down as '' in ' is part of a valid value.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet to set up a simple parser is a parser generator.

Non-trivial parsing code can get complicated quickly, and getting it right without making it horribly slow can easily turn into a huge mess, so the standard solution is to write a basic outline of what type of grammar you want parsed in a domain-specific language and let a parser generator convert that into the actual parsing logic.

If you're working in C#, I'd have a look at [Antlr4CS](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/), a very flexible parser generator that produces C# code.  Like any new coding concept, using ANTLR will take some getting used to, but it works pretty well once you get the basics figured out.

The basic idea is that it will generate the logic for you, creating a parser class that returns a simple parse tree, and you can then use a Listener or Observer to refine that parse tree to suit your needs.  (Familiarity with the Visitor Pattern is helpful.)

Comment: I was hoping to hack through this with having to learn the ins and outs of parsing but it may be time to man up.

Comment: You'll still have to learn about parsing, but the parser generator will take care of all the tedious mechanicals.

Comment: it is a complex grammar.

Answer (score 3):

I'd agree with the advice to write a recursive descent parser. Even if you eventually end up using parser generation tools for jobs like this, it's well worthwhile writing at least one parser by hand using recursive descent (and probably at least one more using the shunting yard algorithm for at least part of the job).

At least in my mind, writing a recursive descent parser starts to give a solid realization of a couple of important points:

1. Taking a task that initially seems almost insurmountable, and defining a solution in a way that's actually quite approachable and tractable.
2. Writing code in a truly systematic way so a set of functions work together as a seamless system.

These may not be strictly necessary, but both of these are extremely valuable for progressing from "hacker" to "software engineer".

A lot of code written by people who haven't had this experience reminds me of the old line about an aircraft being "a collection of spare parts flying in close formation"--code that's next to each other, but doesn't really form a coherent system (though, of course, just writing a parser doesn't guarantee that future code will *necessarily* be a lot better, of course).

Comment: Amen. I think this separates the grownups from the kids. One key mental tool is the idea of *lookahead*. It's hard to write parsers without it, and once you've got it, it simplifies all kinds of code besides parsers.

Comment: When you use small micros, parser generators kinda don't fly.  I was lucky: I was taught at Uni, 30+ years ago, how to roll your own. One of the most useful things ever ever ever. I've used the approaches of scanner + recursive descent parser over and over for real parsers and a number of similar applications over the years. It's powerful, pretty fast and easy to write the code, and just works. In general you end up with a lot of lines of source but it's all simple stuff and can compile down to something quite small - important when you have only kbytes to play in.

Comment: Gotta +1 this as well. I have been taught parser programming by Martin Odersky himself - probably the best course I ever followed - and it's been useful to me *so* many times throughout my career I cannot think of something that is more an eye-opener on the programming world. Well maybe *he* was just fascinating to listen to. Anyway hand-written scanners/lexers/parser/... are immensely powerful tools for many tasks.